# Text based FTP client settings behind a proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, ftp, fedora

I need to create a bash script which will connect to an FTP server, upload a file and close the connection. Usually this would be an easy task but I need to specify some specific proxy settings which is making it difficult.

I can connect to the FTP fine using a GUI client i.e. Filezilla with the following settings:

```
Proxy Settings
--------------
FTP Proxy : USER@HOST
Proxy Host: proxy.domain.com
Proxy User: blank
Proxy Pass: blank
```

[image: Proxy Settings]

```
FTP Settings
------------
Host : 200.200.200.200
Port : 21
User : foo
Pass : bar
```

[image: FTP Settings]

What I can't seem to do is replicate these settings within a text based ftp client i.e. ftp, lftp etc. Can anyone help with setting this script up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html), `lftp` should support the `ftp_proxy` environment variable, e.g.

```
ftp_proxy=ftp://proxy.domain.com lftp -c "cd /upload; put file" ftp://200.200.200.200
```

If that works, you can put

```
export ftp_proxy=ftp://proxy.domain.com
```

in your shell configuration files, or

```
set ftp:proxy=ftp://proxy.domain.com
```

in your ~/.lftprc.

Alternatively, try running the commands that your GUI FTP client is running, e.g.

*upload.lftp*

```
USER ...@...
PASS ...
PUT ...
```

And run it using `-s`:

```
lftp -s upload.lftp 200.200.200.200
```

Or try `curl -T` ([docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)) `ncftpput` ([docs](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html)).

Something like:

```
FTP_PROXY=ftp://proxy.domain.com curl -T uploadfile -u foo:bar ftp://200.200.200.200/myfile
```

might work.

Comment: Mikel : Tried both methods without any luck they just time out. I added some screenshots hopefully then can help?

Comment: @schone: Ah, it looks like it's using an FTP proxy, not an HTTP proxy.  Can you try using `ftp_proxy=ftp://proxy.domain.com lftp...`?

Comment: Brillant! It works! I did the following:

$ export ftp_proxy=proxy.domain.com
$ lftp user:pass@200.200.200.200

:) Thanks!

Comment: @mikel, it should be `set ftp:proxy ftp://proxy.domain.com`, no equal sign after ftp:proxy nice trick though